# Let user enter time in hh:mm:ss in v-text-field

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dzKm.png)
I am doing a Vue js project that allows users to enter the time they used in executing tasks in HH:MM:SS (in the image) which I'll send to backend. but my problem is that I don't know how I can get vuetfy textfield to accept the input in this format. I am supposed to use vuetify textfield, not normal html input.

```
<v-text-field
   filled
   rounded
   dense
   class="rounded-0"
   name="projectTime"
   placeholder="HH:MM:SS"
   v-model="entryEditForm.projectTime"
></v-text-field>
```

Comment: Can you share more details along with your code.

Comment: I have added the code. I however don't know the props to apply to the v-text-field to get the format. I set the type to time but it didn't work because it's project time, so it could be something like 85:33:32 or 00:50:00 depending on the time that was used to execute the task. however, when sending to backend, I am supposed to convert the entire time period and send it in seconds (not hours, mins and sec).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the DatetimePicker component for Vuetify.js

Installation

> npm install --save vuetify-datetime-picker

> import Vue from 'vue' 
> import DatetimePicker from 'vuetify-datetime-picker' 
> import 'vuetify-datetime-picker/src/stylus/main.styl'
>
> Vue.use(DatetimePicker)

Usage

```
<v-datetime-picker
        label="Select Datetime"
        v-model="datetime">
</v-datetime-picker>
```

[date time properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfWFX.png)

[more information on codespots](https://codespots.com/library/item/1255)

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't allow me to enter the time above 24 hrs. so the user cannot enter a task that took 3 days, 37 mins (that's 72:37:00) to complete